# non busy waiting for object initialization

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I would like to do a non busy waiting for a variable to become non-null:

```
while (true)
{
    if (myStaticVar != null)
    {
        break;
    }
}

myStaticVar.DoSomething();
```

The `myStaticVar` could be set any time by any thread.

I am stuck to .net 4, so i can not use async/await.

Comment: Is `myStaticVar` set by another thread? If so use signaling. If not you have to explain a bit more.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: yes, it can be set by any thread.

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110472/using-async-await-on-net-4) if you have VS 2012 you can also use [Microsoft Async 1.0.168](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async)

Comment: You can use this 
http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async
To use Async in .net framework 4

Answer (score 0):

The *correct* solution would be to let your threads communicate via a .NET synchronization primitive such as [`AutoResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx). Lots of examples can be found on SO, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8011832/87698).

That said, manual thread synchronization is a hard problem and easy to get wrong. If your code is not time-critical and you prefer the simplicity of "busy waiting", don't forget to yield processor time while doing so. Either add some `Thread.Sleep` in your loop or use [SpinWait.SpinUntil](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321506(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your variable into a property and use the set accessor to call a delegate.

```
void Main()
{
    _someAction = () => Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");

    myStaticVar = 20;
}

private static Int32 _myStaticVar;
private static Action _someAction;

public static Int32 myStaticVar 
{
    get
    {
        return _myStaticVar;
    }
    set
    {
        _myStaticVar = value;

        if (_someAction != null)
            _someAction();
    }
}
```